# Change text selection method in Windows

Tags: javascript, text, selection, pdf.js, textselection

Is it possible to change text selection method in Windows? If yes, then how?

For example, I'm using Mozilla Pdf.js on my website.(https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html)

Is it possible to implement "Android" text selection like this, so the user will be able to modify the selected text:

[image]

instead of the classic text selection:

[image]

Comment: One thing you could look into is the `::selection` selector in css, may help you achieve part of what you're looking for (but not all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with javascript.

The main part of the selection is [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) object. If we can define range we can define a selection. To define a range we need `startContainer`, `startOffset`, `endContainer` and `endOffset` properties.
The idea of "Android" selection is next: when the mouse is down - remember container and offset at which user has clicked (we can do it fast with `document.caretPositionFromPoint` or `document.caretRangeFromPoint` depending on browser). When the mouse is moving or up - remember the second container and offset. So at every moment, we have `start` and `end` container and offset so we can create a selection:

```
  var range = document.createRange();
  range.setStart(start.container, start.offset);
  range.setEnd(end.container, end.offset);
  var selection = document.getSelection();
  selection.addRange(range);
```

Then, when the mouse is down again we can check if user clicked at the start or at the end of the selection and depending on this information we can 'freeze' start or end point and move the other one. By 'move the other one' I mean recreate selection range.

I've implemented this idea here https://jsfiddle.net/uvaf36gh/. Hopefully, it will help you!